# Python for Data Analysis book chapter 2 Error in reading records

Tags: python

I am learning Python for data analysis from O'Reilly's book [Python for Data Analysis](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do). I am getting following error in command prompt when I am running this command `"records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]"`

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0X92 in position 6:Invalid start byte
```

Please guide me on how to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the JSON file is not created with the UTF-8 encoding. Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using version 2.7.13.